# Как обновлять клавиатуру в боте telegram на python без перезапуска скрипта?

Tags: python, telebot, datetime

Имеется бот с кнопками в виде дат, написанный на telebot.

```
#Первая:
today = datetime.datetime.today()
#Вторая:
today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
#Третья:
today + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
```

Запускаем скрипт, кнопки соответствуют датам. При работе скрипта до 00.00 все идеально, а как наступает следующий день, кнопки не обновляются, остаются те же даты, что и в предыдущий день. Это касается как inline клавиатуры, так и обычной. Как решить эту проблему?
Очевидное решение - автоматический перезапуск скрипта каждые 24 ч. Пока не нашёл варианта, как сделать это правильно. Какие есть варианты и какой из них лучше? Можно ли это сделать без перезапуска скрипта?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать проверку таким образом:

```
timetest = datetime.datetime.now()
timetest = timetest.strftime("%d")
if timetest == 1: #вместо 1 вводим нужный нам день по счёту.
    #...
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена переносом переменных с датами из глобальных в локальные